# How is the MD5 digest calculated in BGP?

Tags: hash, md5

The RFC is very superficial on the implementation details. What is the injective function being used?

[RFC (ietf)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2385)

MD5 digest is produced by applying the MD5 algorithm to these items in the following order:

```
   1. the TCP pseudo-header (in the order: source IP address,
      destination IP address, zero-padded protocol number, and
      segment length)
   2. the TCP header, excluding options, and assuming a checksum of
      zero
   3. the TCP segment data (if any)
   4. an independently-specified key or password, known to both TCPs
      and presumably connection-specific
```

How are the above items concatenated? I wasn't able to find much information, could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to crypto.SE. Your question is about practice in a communication protocol, thus borderline on-[topic](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Pretending that it is, I see no other way to interpret the RFC than as specifying concatenation of the bytes forming each field.

Comment: Back on topic, two remarks: A) There is no provision for a password-to-key transformation, which is a flaw since it makes password guessing practical when a password (rather than a key) is used. B) The construction really tries to perform a MAC, but does not use HMAC, and uses a hash which collision resistance is trounced. The combination allows an adversary able to predict 1 and 2  to prepare two variants of 3 which can be substituted without detection. HMAC-MD5 would have avoided that. Another example of poor crypto design in legacy network protocols.